# objective c send cookies to uiwebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, cookies, uiwebview

I need to send cookies for login to a UIWebView, but when I load the web page the cookies haven't been sent.

My code is:

**CorreoViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title =AMLocalizedString(@"Correo", @"");
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://cuentas.uv.es/cgi-bin/p/user/Usuario"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSArray * cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies];
    NSDictionary * headers = [NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies: cookies];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"Post"];
    [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];
    [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];

    NSLog(@"Request: %@", [[request allHTTPHeaderFields] objectForKey:@"cookie"]);

    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

And the cookies I have in my cookie storage are:

> COOKIE 0: NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:"PAPIAuthNcook"
>   value:"nBNqHJSdjgo1aBw0uGh3AXzElIHCxA%2FDbnipSHWZbU5Eh1cJfUr18GEP9zxB%2Bl%2FZGPBAKQu6oF2l%0AzIMt7ywiSECLBuOHJnvS7y6rVim2HfE%3D%0A"
>   expiresDate:(null) created:2014-01-16 15:05:41 +0000 (4.11578e+08)
>   sessionOnly:TRUE domain:"cuentas.uv.es" path:"/" isSecure:FALSE
>
> COOKIE 1: NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:"PAPIslist"
>   value:"17201128679244079|https://uvapp.uv.es/" expiresDate:(null)
>   created:2014-01-16 15:05:41 +0000 (4.11578e+08) sessionOnly:TRUE
>   domain:"cuentas.uv.es" path:"/" isSecure:FALSE
>
> COOKIE 2: NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:"PAPIAuthNcook"
>   value:"nBNqHJSdjgo1aBw0uGh3AXzElIHCxA%2FDbnipSHWZbU5Eh1cJfUr18GEP9zxB%2Bl%2FZGPBAKQu6oF2l%0AzIMt7ywiSECLBuOHJnvS7y6rVim2HfE%3D%0A"
>   expiresDate:(null) created:2014-01-16 15:05:41 +0000 (4.11578e+08)
>   sessionOnly:TRUE domain:"as.uv.es" path:"/" isSecure:FALSE
>
> COOKIE 3: NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:"PAPIslist"
>   value:"17201128679244079|https://uvapp.uv.es/" expiresDate:(null)
>   created:2014-01-16 15:05:41 +0000 (4.11578e+08) sessionOnly:TRUE
>   domain:"as.uv.es" path:"/" isSecure:FALSE

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comment this lines:

```
 NSArray * cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies];
    NSDictionary * headers = [NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies: cookies];
[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
```

the cookies are sent automatically. I hope this will serve you.

Comment: I comment the above lines but its not working.How did it take the cookies automatically