# Why iOS UIWebView Video doesn't send cookie?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have a UIWebView, and load a html page from my website:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [webView loadRequest:nsUrlRequest];
}
```

then I want load some images/videos from the webview:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)myView
{
        // this line I got video url
        NSString* videoUrl = XXXXX;

         // cookie is all right in the page
         [myView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"alert(document.cookie)"];

        // image load request is correct with cookie
        [myView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.createElement('img').src='/Images/logo.png'"]];

        // but video request no cookie !!!!!
        [myView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"var video = document.createElement('video');video.src = '%@';video.autoPlay = true;", videoUrl]];

}
```

Please help me!! Save me !!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled cookies for the webview in iPhone 
try using :

```
[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage].cookieAcceptPolicy = 
    NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways;
```

And to send cookies please check this stack link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21253352/2098690

Comment: cookie all right in the webview, it just doesn't sent with video request, but image request is ok....

Comment: I have added NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways

Comment: @ArielZhang Try this  `NSArray *cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies];
    NSDictionary * headers = [NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies: cookies];
[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];`

Comment: how do I get the request ? actually, the video's request was call server automatic after I set the video's src by javascript.

Comment: I see the same problem in the webview in osx. did you find a solution?