# How to maintain cookie in iOS?

Tags: ios, cookies, uiwebview, nshttpcookiestorage

I'm trying to do login using `UIWebView`. On success it stores cookie in `NSHTTPCookieStorage`. It's working fine for a single session.

But if I force close the app and come back to app, it ask me for login. Whereas it's cookie is already stored.

Also I referred this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/8713316/2594560. But my `sessionOnly:FALSE` and expiration date is also set.

Below is code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https:serverURL/show_all")!)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

If user is not login then this will redirect to login page, but if user is login then it should display this "show_all" page. It works with the cookie. But if I force close app and restart app, then it's redirecting to login.

Please guide me how to achieve this.

Comment: Please show some code ?

Comment: where is code for cookie ? when you force close app your webview don't have that previous cookie with it and it tries to create new one.

Comment: But when I check NSHTTPCookieStorage on viewDidLoad() I'm able to get the cookie value

Comment: yes it is in the stored in variable but not in webview, I think you have to set that in webview

Comment: But UIWebView won't automatically take cookie value from NSHTTPCookieStorage?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95296/discussion-between-ankita-shah-and-varun-naharia).

Comment: please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21165633/objective-c-send-cookies-to-uiwebview